# Artifacts when using DoF, transparency and VSE

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor, artifacts, depth-of-field

I'm rendering a scene with Cycles and using it in another scene's VSE as a scene strip. It has transparent film settings, and depth of field effect. After putting this together in VSE, along with black background strip, I'm getting weird artifacts when using alpha over compositing. They go away when I use add compositing, but that "takes away" a bit of the image I think. Is this a premultiplied alpha kind of problem? What do I do?

Artifact

[image]

VSE

[image]
[image]

Alpha of the render from source scene

[image]

Comment: What is the artefact? Does this solved your issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158880/2214 ?

Comment: @vklidu that's almost (if not) the same as using add compositing, and that is different to what I see when I render the scene with black (instead of transparent) background. I can live with it, but it bothers me I don't understand what's going on. I think I'm going to put together minimal .blend file showing it and file a ticket with blender's issue tracker.